# Writing my own strcopy Function in C using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create my own string copy function in C.
Copying the text works, however extra characters are added to the destination string at the end and I don't know why.
I would be very happy to get an answer.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
void copy(char *dst, char *src) {
    int src_len = strlen(src);
    char *src_strtng = &src[0];
    char *dst_strtng = &dst[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < src_len; i++) {
        *dst_strtng++ = *src_strtng++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", dst);
}
 
int main() {
    char srcString[] = "We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize!";
    char dstString[strlen(srcString)];
    copy(dstString, srcString);
}
```

Comment: You don't 0-terminate dst, and you also allocate 1 too few bytes for dst (2 too few once you terminate dst).

Comment: Please don't post images of code, post code as text

Comment: How would I 0-terminate dst (with a while loop, wich ends, when src_strtd end = '\0'?) and why should I allocate 1 too few bytes for dst?
But thank you!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You'd 0 terminate it by adding the '\0' character at the end of the string. This tells C when the string ends and is also called null terminating. I'd recommend doing some research on how strings work in C cuz it might help

Comment: In [tag:C], "strings" are `char` arrays with a special `\0` character at the end. Ex: `char str[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'];` You need to take this into account.

Comment: Yes, I knew that, but not where to add '0' to dst.
But Thank you! :-)

Comment: Add at *dst_strtng

Comment: Ok, I think I got a solution. I can just let the program walk through the for loop one more time and by that, it is adding the '0' automaticly.
(`
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
 
void copy(char* dst, char* src){
  int src_len = strlen(src);
  char *src_strtng = &src[0];
  char *dst_strtng = &dst[0];
  for (int i = 0; i<src_len+1;i++){
    *dst_strtng++=*src_strtng++;
  }
  printf("%s\n",dst);
}
 
int main(){
  char srcString[] = "We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize!";
  char dstString[strlen(srcString)+1];
  copy(dstString,srcString);
}
`)

Comment: @emil_pelle don't post code other then small one liners in a comment. As you can see it's unreadable. OTOH you can answer your own question.

Comment: @emil_pelle hint: you don't need `strlen`.

Comment: Why not? 
Thank you!

Comment: @emil_pelle simply end the loop if the character copied is the null character whose absence was the cause of the problem. Using strlen is inefficient, because you scan the stzring to copy twice, once in strlen and once in your loop.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Interestingly, using `strlen()` is a good first step if `copy()` needed to cope with overlapping strings.  But since `strcpy()` does not need to handle overlap, `copy()` need not either and `strlen()` not needed as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

> create my own str copy function in C.

**Missing *null character* termination**

This is OP's key issue, lack of appending a *null character* to `dst`.

**Only need to traverse `src` once**

Rather than `strlen()` in `copy()`, just look for `'\0'`. <sup>*1</sup>

**Does not return a `char *`**

Save the destination pointer.

**Prints output, yet `strcpy()` does not print anything.**

**Missing `const` for data referenced by `src`**

**Pedantic concern: `str` should act as if `char` was `unsigned char`** <sup>*2</sup>

```
char *copy(char* dst, const char* src) {
  unsigned char *udst = (unsigned char *) dst;
  const unsigned char *usrc = (const unsigned char *) src;

  do {
    *udst++ = *usrc;
  } while (*usrc++);
  return dst;
}
```

**Allocate enough space for the length of a *string* and a *null character***

`strlen()` returns the *length* of a *string*.  That does not include the final *null character*.

```
int main() {
  char srcString[] = "We promptly judged ...";
  char dstString[strlen(srcString) + 1]; // Add 1
  copy(dstString,srcString);
  puts(dstString);  // Print here, not in copy().
}
```

---

<sup>*1</sup> C's `strcpy()` is `char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);`

Note the `restrict`.  This implies access via the pointer is not affected by other code.  E.g. source string and destination will not overlap.

```
// Better as
char *copy(char* restrict dst, const char* restrict src) {
```

OP's use of `strlen()` in `copy()` **is** a good first step to handle overlapping memory (see following), but `strcpy()` does not need to handle that - suggest `copy()` not deal with overlap.

```
char *copy_handle_overlap(char* dst, const char* src) {
  return memmove(dst, src, strlen(src) + 1);
}
```

---

<sup>*2</sup>  C string functions have:

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).

This is important for the rare non-2's complement to distinguish `+0` from `-0`.

Non-2's complement support expected to be dropped with C2X.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot!
But for what reason, shouldn't I do this like this:

`#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>
 
void copy(char* dst, char* src){

  int i = 0;

  char *src_strtng = &src[0];

  char *dst_strtng = &dst[0];

  while (src_strtng[i]!='0'){

    *dst_strtng++=*src_strtng++;

  }
  dst_strtng[i+1] = '0';

  printf("%s\n",dst);

}
 
int main(){

  char srcString[] = "We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize!";

  char dstString[strlen(srcString)+1];

  copy(dstString,srcString);

}`

Comment: @emil_pelle That code 1) appends the null character in the wrong place, 2) uses wrong index type for huge strings, 3) prints output - `strcpy()` does not do that. 4) does not return a `char *` 5) other  issues.